# How can I "associate" two variables to a position in a bi-dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have a bi-dimensional array with 8 elements in each dimension and I have two variables (x, y) with values from 0 to 7 each. I need to "associate" each value of those variables to the array position. Im positive that I must use pointers for this but I just can't figure it out by myself.

As an example, I have these two variables with 2 random values from 0 to 7.

```
int x = 3;
int y= 4;

int a [8][8];
```

I need to assign the `x=3` and the `y=4` to the array as the element position:
`a[3][4].`

I will need to do this for every case, meaning, from x=0 to x=7 and y=0 to y=7, all the array position elements must be associated with the possible x and y variables values.

Comment: Are you familiar with for loops in C? [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm) would be a good start.

Comment: The  element at position `a[3][4]` has type `int` hence you can not "associate" two different integers to it except you use bit manipulation and store one value into the high word and the other one into the low word but then you might need fixed width integers. Anyways it is not really clear what you are asking have you tried anything yourself yet? What exactly do you mean with "associate" how is the value accessed later?

Comment: The expression `a[x][y]` associates `x` and `y` with the array element at row `x` and column `y`—the C implementation does the address arithmetic for you. What more do you want?

Comment: You can use x and y to index into the array, each pair will reference a value in the int grid. To run through all combinations you can use 2 nested for loops.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Maybe you should explain what you are _actually_  trying to achieve. What should the content of the `a` array be??

Comment: Do you need an array of a structure type?  `struct not_very_sensible { int value; int x; int y; };` might work, but the idea isn't very sensible.  There is no obvious reason to store the position of the value in the structure holding the value.  Maybe there's an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) lurking here; you're trying to do something but can't, so you've thought of an alternative way of doing it but you're having problems with that too.  Maybe you should ask about the original problem — in a new question since this one has an answer, albeit one that probably isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 loops, 1 nested in other

```
for (x = 0; x <= 7; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y <= 7; y++) {
        a[x][y] = something;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should typically write `for (x  =  0; x < 8; x++)`.